# WordPress Post Order

Tags: theme-development

I am creating my own theme. Is there any way to order the posts by the category name? So if the category name is X, set it on the top of the ordered list.

Is there any way to do that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can achieve this developing custom code using https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: @VinodDalvi WP_Query has no facilities to order by terms.

Comment: @Rarst Sorry i was not clear enough but i meant to say which you said in your answer "Querying posts with specific category separately and excluding category for the other query."

Answer (score 0):

While a common request, WP is quite opinionated that taxonomies are strictly a *grouping* mechanism and not meant for meaningful order.

You *can* achieve this literally, but it takes quite a bit of [custom SQL](http://scribu.net/wordpress/sortable-taxonomy-columns.html) inserted into query logic.

Alternately you could consider splitting your query for your specific requirements. Such as querying posts with specific category separately and excluding category for the other query.